# Press and hold 'x' and delete just until the cursor

Tags: neovim

Is it possible to press and hold the 'x' and just delete all characters after the cursor? currently when I hold the 'x' and all the characters after the cursor were deleted, it also deletes characters before the cursor.

Comment: Not that I know of. Frankly, if you're doing this, you're using Vim wrong. Vim is all about the action-movement combination. Apply a delete to end-of-line/next-word/all-characters-up-to-X, etc. See `:h motion.txt` in its entirety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`:h D`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#D) and more generally for [`:h change.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#change.txt) which might help you using the right command for the right action.

<kbd>x</kbd> is meant to suppress the characters individually (the one under the cursor), <kbd>D</kbd> is meant to suppress all the characters until the end of the line.

Now if you really want to remap <kbd>x</kbd> to behave like you described in your question, it is possible but that would be pretty over-engineered when you already have a built-in action which does what you want.

Comment: I think I remember I'm able to do this when I was just starting building my vimrc but I cant reproduce it anymore even with `nvim -u NONE`. maybe some plugin or an option? PS: I know about the 'change.txt' but my finger is kinda hurting to reach for the shift key.

Comment: @JohnFredFadrigalan If there is a plugin which remaps `x` to get this behavior I'm not aware of it. Still I strongly encourage you to get used to use the right action with the right range because that is what makes the power of Vim: you have different actions which are meant to be used in different contexts to operate on different ranges: keeping `x` pressed for a second waiting for the line to get duplicated completely is way less efficient than pressing `shift+d` once :)

Answer (score 0):

`D` will delete the rest of the line, and `dw` will delete the word starting with the character in front of your cursor.